# PyTest: How to make sure that the tests run only when the pre tests passes in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, hook, fixtures

Consider i am having set of tests that are having module fixtures that are setting up data necessary for tests. But when something fails in the module setup data, all the tests get failed which gives the wrong impression that tests are failing. Ideally tests should be skipped if module setup data is failing and only pass when everything is setup in module setup data.

There is a plugin called 'pytest-dependency' where a test is dependent on another test and only runs when dependent tests passes. But in my case,it will be the method in the fixtures and this plugin cant be used. I remember reading somewhere that hook implementation can be donw where you know which fixture is executing and then change the test outcome. Can anyone throw more light on this?

Comment: *"which gives the wrong impression that tests are failing"* I'd say the impression is total accurate: the tests have failed. In your scenario it would be appropriate to raise an exception if the setup step has fails instead of using an `assert`.

Comment: Ideally speaking, tests are not failing with respect to functionality but due to the setup module data. Hence there is no point in running the tests rather skip it and provide appropriate reasons so that execution will also be faster.